# Can Kotlin be defined a strongly typed language?

Tags: kotlin, strong-typing

From the definition of strongly-typed language:

> A strongly-typed programming language is one in which each type of
>   data (such as integer, character, hexadecimal, packed decimal, and so
>   forth) is predefined as part of the programming language and all
>   constants or variables defined for a given program must be described
>   with one of the data types ([source](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/strongly-typed))

From kotlin documentation, I can understand that kotlin is a **statically typed** language because the type of the variable is known at compile time, but what about strongly or weakly typed? I can't find any clear response googling. As far as I understood Kotlin should be equally strongly typed as Java because it compiles down to Java byte code, but I'm not 100% sure. Please help me to understand if I'm on the right way.

Comment: It has type inference, but the types cannot be reassigned, so it's strict.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Weakly-typed languages feature implicit conversions between *incompatible* types while strongly-typed languages disallow it.

Kotlin doesn't feature implicit conversions between types - which makes it **strongly statically typed**.

Comment: Mmm.  In fact, Kotlin is even more strongly typed than Java, in that it lacks Java's implicit numeric conversions (widening `int` to `long`, &c).  Including nullability in the type system could also be seen as making it stronger.